# Why did Apple choose to design its programming language with future and past tense method names?

Tags: ios, language-design, objective-c

There are a lot of methods like this in iOS/Objective C:

```
- viewDidLoad
- viewWillAppear:
- applicationDidFinishLaunching
```

I've just been having a discussion with some colleagues about this design choice and why they would choose to be so verbose in preference of the more "standard" ways of event propagation for instance:

```
- onViewLoad
- onViewAboutToAppear
- onApplicationFinishLaunching
```

I didn't have an answer and rather put it down to just personal preference of the team designing the language. However, I'm wondering if there's more to it - whether this is a preferred option. Or whether the team just wanted to differentiate themselves from other languages, or from the norm.

If anyone has any insight that would be very interesting.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe it's a carryover from some Smalltalk conventions?  I'm not too knowledgeable about Smalltalk so I can only speculate.

Comment: Historical nit:  Objective-C was invented in the early 1980s at a small company called Productivity Products International which later became called Stepstone.

Comment: I wouldn't call those examples "more verbose", when overall they are shorter than the standard names you prefer.  I do agree that they are rather awkward sounding, though.

Comment: @dan1111 `viewWillAppear:` sounds more awkward than `onViewAboutToAppear`? Not to these ears.

Comment: My issue is that "viewDidLoad" is true any time after the view has loaded. The callback name should emphasize it occurs just after the view has loaded, not at some arbitrary point later. In the same manner "viewWillAppear" is a statement which is true any time before the view appears; the name should make it obvious the view is about to appear.

Comment: @JosephEarl Perhaps, but there are dozens, maybe even hundreds of should/will/did methods in Cocoa and Cocoa Touch classes. You learn the convention once and they all work the same way. Also, you really shouldn't make any assumptions about exactly when you get those messages: all you should count on is that the view is available after `-viewDidLoad` and it hasn't yet appeared in `-viewWillAppear`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the rationale is that in Objective-C, selectors are supposed to be messages sent to the objects. Sending `[viewController onViewAppear:]` makes it sound like you're going to pass it a lambda telling it what to do, whereas `[viewController viewWillAppear:]` is better under the "I am sending this message to that object" paradigm. (I find it weird that the `animated` flag isn't in the selector in this case though.)

From there it makes sense to reduce length and extraneous particles by preferring future tense `-viewWillAppear:` over `-viewAboutToAppear:`.

Comment: This sounds like a really reasonable and logical explanation. It does sound much better to call `[viewController viewWillAppear]` than `[viewController onViewAboutToAppear]`.

Answer (score 4):

> Or whether the team just wanted to differentiate themselves from other languages, or from the norm.

First, I'll point out that the names in question come from frameworks, not from the programming language (Objective-C) itself.

It's impossible to say what the team was thinking unless you were part of it, but I'd imagine that the names come from the fact that the methods are called before or after a given event has happened. For example, `-viewWillAppear` is called just *before* the view is shown on the screen, and `-viewDidAppear` is called just after the view is shown. Together, these methods let you prepare for something that's about to happen and respond to something that just happened. I don't think these names were chosen just to be different from other frameworks (indeed, the frameworks from NextStep that became Cocoa predate many of today's object frameworks), but more likely were just meant to be descriptive.

Note that the *...Did...* and *...Will...* methods aren't the only ways that events are communicated to your code. For example, touches have a more complex lifecycle, so you have methods like `-touchesBegan:...`, `-touchesMoved:...`, `-touchesEnded:...`, and `-touchesCancelled:...`.

Comment: Its likely one of those things where they started to write the touch events first and by following the proper convention they were tasked to used they decided to apply it to all events.  They also could have thought it was funny and wanted somebody to post this very question 4 years later on a Stack Exchange website.

Answer (score 0):

The only comparison to go on that I have experience with is Microsoft's event patterns.

Microsoft frameworks use two styles for these events one in Windows Forms and ASP.NET Web Forms, the other appears in WPF/Silverlight/WinRT.

In Forms based applications, the framework uses imperfect tense for (something's happening) and perfect tense for (something happened). One example is INotifyPropertyChanging/INotifyPropertyChanged interface pair (which provide the PropertyChanging and PropertyChanged events, respectively).

For WPF et al, the framework uses Preview[EventName] and EventName. No past tense is used here for example PreviewMouseClick and MouseClick are the event pair for a mouse click event.

I think the choice between the three naming methods is subjective as long as they are consistently used within a given framework.